# Cloning Android Phone

Tags: backup, rom-flashing, data-transfer

Is there a way to image an android phone and flash that image onto another Android phone WITHOUT rooting the device? I don't want to just backup the data onto a new phone. I want to completely clone the system. If you know of a way to do this by rooting the phone, please also include that. If I absolutely have to root the phone, I will, but I want to do it without rooting the device.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you would have two identical devices (from hardware perspective) cloning an device is impossible for most modern devices because devices are by default hardware encrypted.

This means that there is a special section in your flash that is bound to your CPU, not to the type of your CPU but to the CPU chip in your device. This section contains the the encryption keys which are therefore bound to the CPU.

Even if you would manage to copy the complete content of the flash chip to a second identical device the new CPU would not be able to decrypt the CPU bound section and therefore all your user data could not be decrypted.